# Bug with user removal and going over 200 point per day cap?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, reputation-history

I've noticed from time to time that when a user is removed from the system that I'll receive a -10. However if I'm over the 200/day cap and this happens, any further upvotes do not count.

[image: ss#1]

This seems like a bug, where another of the skipped upvotes would now be counted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong day for votes that should be realculated to count. The vote that was invalidated due to a removed user did not necessary get cast that day. It's much more likely that a vote was invalidated from some other day in your past, and the removal is only shown today for accounting purposes.

If you were capped *on the day that vote was cast*, then yes, another vote would be recalculated to give you the 10 reputation lost from that vote disappearing. Also keep in mind that the system [doesn't recalculate your reputation every time a vote is cast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351556), so even if the vote that was invalidated was from the same day, you wouldn't get the reputation moved to another vote until you were scheduled for another full recalculation.

Comment: That's kind of what I suspected but wanted to double check, thanks for taking the time to explain this.